# How to get derivatives using apache lib

Tags: java, apache, apache-commons, derivative, differentiation

I am using apache library to compute derivates. what I want to do is to get the derivates of the following
equation

```
2+(2*x^2)+(3*x)+5
```

I followed the below posted code but I am a bit confused regarding the parameters stated below.
Please help me to find out how to get the derivatives of the above equation.

**code**:

```
int params = 1;
int order = 2;
double xRealValue = 5;
DerivativeStructure x = new DerivativeStructure(params, order, 0,  
    xRealValue);
DerivativeStructure y = x.pow(2);                    //COMPILE ERROR
Log.i(TAG, "y = " + y.getValue());
Log.i(TAG, "y = " + y.getPartialDerivative(1));
Log.i(TAG, "y = " + y.getPartialDerivative(2));
```

Comment: which library version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

commons-math3 version 3.6 does not give any compilation error, and your code works.

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.differentiation.DerivativeStructure;
```

your equation can be written as below

```
int xValue = 5;

int howManyUnknowParamsHasFunction = 1;
int howManyDeriviationWillYouTake = 2;
int whatIsTheIndexOfThisParameterX = 0;

DerivativeStructure x = new DerivativeStructure(howManyUnknowParamsHasFunction, howManyDeriviationWillYouTake, whatIsTheIndexOfThisParameterX, xValue);

// x --> x^2.
DerivativeStructure x2 = x.pow(2);

//y = 2x^2 + 3x + 7
DerivativeStructure y = new DerivativeStructure(2.0, x2, 3.0, x).add(7);
```

Comment: what is .add(7)??why 7

Comment: you have 2 and 5 which are summed, so I added 7, if you want you can seperate it .add(5).add(2)

Comment: i copied your answer, but x is hihglighted with red "cant be resolved2 would you please tell me how to define x

Comment: @user2121 your x definition was correct so i did not add it. I have updated the answer also.

Comment: would u please explain briefly the meaning of the parameters of the definition of x?? i mean "params, order, index and xRealValue" because i just put these value randomly without knowing their meaning

Comment: @user2121 I updated the answer with meaningful variable names. I hope this helps you to better understand it.